# Kendo UI PanelBar - Remove automatic style on selected panel

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I'm implementing a Kendo PanelBar on my webpage. I'm pretty new to CSS/HTML, so I'm lost on how to remove a default style on the PanelBar. When I select a panel, it opens properly and looks fine. When I move the mouse away from the open panel, there is an orange border that appears on the open panel. I have attached two images showing the issue.

Everything looks fine when I hover on the open panel:

[image]

When I move the mouse away, there is an orange border:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to remove this border?

Answer (score 2):

I was challenged with the same issue and submitted a ticket to kendo support. Iliana Nikolova supplied the following:

```
.k-panelbar .k-state-focused.k-state-selected {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

In my solution, the panelBar box shadow was still showing, I then used page inspector (F12) and tested following rule using the box-shadow:none; property and that did the trick for me.

```
.k-state-selected > .k-link, .k-panelbar > li > .k-state-selected, .k-panelbar > li.k-state-default > .k-state-selected.k-link {
            background-color: #C7D3A9;
            color:black;
            box-shadow: none;
}
```

Before your post I was searching the a boat ton of code and getting no place. I used the recommendation of using theme builder and took a video (using windows media encoder 9), I feel by illustrating the problem it helped generate a better kendo response. Iliana didn't return my code with the fix so this left me hanging but he did supply the key element.

If you find this solves the issue please vote answered. Others who also find this helpful please also  provide positive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what element it is, because you did not give the exact code.

But you can use a simple css, find the element and apply the css to remove the orange border.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Use the Kendo Theme Builder here at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/ and then load the default theme. You should see the themebuilder panel appear in the bottom right corner of your screen. Look for "Widget States" drop down. You will see the options there and you can change the orange border color.

Now if you want to completely remove the orange border and active state, you will need to open up the kendo.default.min.css file and do a CNTRL+F (Find) for the hex color code #f35800. Look at the selectors carefully to make sure you are modifying the correct style (i.e. .k-state-selected)

Then when you are sure you've got the right selector(s), change the color to "transparent" (i.e. border-color:transparent)

This worked for me